# Does this simplify to (r^4/8)(a-sin(a))

Tags: integration

[image]

The full question was:

[image]

Find the moment of inertia of this shaded area about the x-axis.
Equation to find this is I(x)= $\int y^2\,dA$

How I tried to solve it:

[image]

[image]

Above on the paper, was my attempt to integrate it. Yet I can't simplify it further. I know now the easier method, but I heard that this method works aswell. That it will result in the same answer namely: $ \frac {r^4}{8}$(a-sin(a))

Comment: Anyone downvoting should explain their reasoning. Of questions that ask about homework-esque problems, this is a very well-written one and exhibits a clear attempt at a solution and a desire to understand the material.

Comment: I agree. There is no objective reason for the downvote. Maybe, it was an accidentical downvote.

Comment: Some people tend to downvote non-texed questions. Eventhough a lot of effort has gone into it.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $y=r\sin\theta$ in the first integral gives $\displaystyle\int_0^B(r^2\sin^2\theta) r^2\cos^2\theta\;d\theta=r^4\int_0^B\frac{1}{4}\sin^22\theta\;d\theta$

$\displaystyle=\frac{r^4}{4}\int_0^B\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 4\theta)d\theta=\frac{r^4}{8}\big[\theta-\frac{1}{4}\sin4\theta\big]_0^B=\frac{r^4}{8}\big[\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta(1-2\sin^2\theta)\big]_0^B$

$\displaystyle=\frac{r^4}{8}\big[\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta+2\sin^3\theta\cos\theta\big]_0^B=\frac{r^4}{8}\big[B-\sin B\cos B+2\sin^3 B\cos B\big]$

$\displaystyle=\frac{r^4}{8}\big[B-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2B+2\sin^3 B\cos B\big]$.

Since the second integral gives $\displaystyle\big[\frac{1}{4}y^4\big]_0^{r\sin B}\cdot\cot B=\frac{1}{4}r^4\sin^4 B\cot B=\frac{r^4}{4}\sin^3B\cos B$,

subtracting the two integrals and multplying by 2 yields

$\displaystyle\frac{r^4}{4}\big[B-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2B\big]=\frac{r^4}{4}\big[\frac{\alpha}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin\alpha\big]=\frac{r^4}{8}\big[\alpha-\sin\alpha\big]$